# Firewalld forward port with VirtualBox IP is always 10.0.2.2, drops source IP

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, virtualbox, firewalld

I am trying to setup web server with virtual box in it.

This is my setup:

```
# this does nothing
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --permanent 
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8080 --permanent
# with masquerade on/off, zone=external, no change
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

I have `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`

- Host machine (Centos 7) port: 80
- VirtualBox (Ubuntu 16.04) port: 8080

It works, but virtual machine **sees all communication coming from `10.0.2.2`**. How to make host machine firewall not dropping the source IP?

I am sure it's possible without changing virtualbox configuration. I rebuild system using automated scripts, it used to work.

What am I missing? I don't want to use bridge on vm

Edit: [I also tried switching zone to 'external' and realized MASQUERADE is not to be found in iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/866045/firewalld-is-not-masquerading)

Comment: the forward-port also include a toaddr: "firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=8080:toaddr=10.0.2.x", ip of the vm.

Comment: @AndreasM host machine doesn't see 10.0.x.x network, only virtual machine do

Comment: After spend too much time on it I just bridged virtual machine...

Comment: For the record, you can't actually do what you wanted because it's NAT.

Comment: @NathanC so how routers do it? I am 99% positive I managed to do it in first instance then I screwed something up

Answer (score 1):

As I can remember, IP address `10.0.x.x` configured on VirtualBox VM only when you configure network as `NAT`. That's the reason why you see all requests from `10.0.2.2`. To fix it you should change network to bridged.

This issue easily could be found in Google. In my google it's [first link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=43500).

Comment: Not only I said that in question "I don't want to use bridge on vm" but see me third comment under the question

Comment: @Peter sorry, my fault, But if you check my link to VirtualBox forum, latest comment show how to solve your issue without creating bridge.